# phonegap 3.5 document.addEventListener deviceready not working

Tags: android, cordova, addeventlistener

I installed phonegap and then I installed cordova from cmd using npm (nodejs)

I have phonegap 3.5

My problem is  **document.addEventListener deviceready** is not working in index.html

I also add alert in my index.js at this :

```
onDeviceReady: function() {
    app.receivedEvent('deviceready');

    alert('test ready');


},
```

which is also not working.

I copied cordova.js from "platforms\android\assets\www to my index.html

what is app.initialize(); and what's the link between index.js and app.initialize();

Can someone explain or any link with all details?

I have to put **app.initialize();** in index.js?

Thank you..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This Questions imply that you have not read the [Cordova Documentation](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.5.0/). Please read this first.

You have to build your project via your terminal/console, and not just make a copy of files into a folder.

Comment: hey i already read that doc. I'm running in my command prompt. For building phonegap build android and for running - phonegap run android.